# How do I get rid of a white line between containers in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having trouble identifying and getting rid of two white lines between my div blocks in WordPress.

Here's a link: http://getkingofspades.com/en/

Between the 8th & 9th block, there's a 16px white line and also at the bottom before the footer there's a white line. These appeared after my programmer did some modifications to the footer.

I haven't been abe to figure out what they are and how to delete them. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: The footer one is easy. You have a rogue &#65279; character just before the footer div. As for the other gap. I can't see anything glaringly obvious. However, there are a lot of HTML errors when you run it through the validator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fgetkingofspades.com%2Fen%2F Maybe fix them and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, the &#65279; was easy. And I accidentally stumbled upon the cause for the middle white line. There was a random empty <p> </p> at the end of the 8th block causing this.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a hack but it should work to fix your problem.

Try this:

```
#t-block-10 {
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

And then find and remove the following from your markup:

```
&#65279;
```

Comment: Surely adding the negative margin isn't resolving the real issue here? That's just a hacky workaround. Find the real source of the issue and fix it properly.

Comment: I thought I mentioned that it was a hack. Editing now. Thanks for pointing that out.